# Transform a matrix txt file in spectra data for ChemoSpec package

Tags: r, windows-7

I want to use ChemoSpec with a mass spectra of about 60'000 datapoint.

I have them already in one txt file as a matrix (X + 90 samples = 91 columns; 60'000 rows).

How may I adapt this file as spectra data without exporting again each single file in csv format (which is quite long in R given the size of my data)?

Comment: Put in dput( head(txt-matrix) )

Comment: This will require some poking around within the guts of `getManyCsv` within the `ChemoSpec` package.  The authors of `ChemoSpec` have adopted a slightly idiosyncratic (but I'm sure useful for their target audience) way of reading input in a particular format, which will probably have to be worked around by someone who knows enough R coding to delve into the guts of the existing R code and adapt it ... (and wants to take the time).  Part of the issue here is that (since there are 3095 packages on CRAN) finding someone who knows the details of a particular package can be tough ...

Answer (score 0):

The typical (and only?) way to import data into ChemoSpec is by way of the ***getManyCsv()*** function, which as the question indicates requires one CSV file for each sample.

Creating 90 CSV files from the 91 columns - 60,000 rows file described, may be somewhat slow and tedious in R, but could be done with a standalone application, whether existing utility or some ad-hoc script.

An R-only solution would be to **create a new method, say *getOneBigCsv()*, adapted from *getManyCsv()***.  After all, [the logic of getManyCsv()](https://github.com/bryanhanson/ChemoSpec/blob/master/R/getManyCsv.R) is relatively straight forward.
Don't expect such a solution to be sizzling fast, but it should, in any case, compare  with the time it takes to run getManyCsv() and avoid having to create and manage the many files, hence overall be faster and certainly less messy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. My samples are not so well separated with this approach. I will try again with smaller datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed your question 2 days ago.  I'm the author of `ChemoSpec` - always feel free to write directly to me in addition to posting somewhere.

The solution is straightforward.  You already have your data in a matrix (after you read it in with `>read.csv("file.txt")`.  So you can use it to manually create a `Spectra` object.  In the R console type `?Spectra` to see the structure of a Spectra object, which is a list with specific entries.  You will need to put your X column (which I assume is mass) into the freq slot.  Then the rest of the data matrix will go into the data slot.  Then manually create the other needed entries (making sure the data types are correct).  Finally, assign the Spectra class to your completed list by doing something like `>class(my.spectra)` <- "Spectra" and you should be good to go.  I can give you more details on or off list if you describe your data a bit more fully.   Perhaps you have already solved the problem?

By the way, `ChemoSpec` is totally untested with MS data, but I'd love to find out how it works for you.  There may be some changes that would be helpful so I hope you'll send me feedback.

Good Luck, and let me know how else I can help.

Answer (score 0):

many years passed and I am not sure if anybody is still interested in this topic. But I had the same problem and did a little workaround to convert my data to class 'Spectra' by extracting the information from the data itself:

```
#Assumption:
# Data is stored as a numeric data.frame with column names presenting samples
# and row names including domain axis

dataframe2Spectra <- function(Spectrum_df,
                              freq = as.numeric(rownames(Spectrum_df)),
                              data = as.matrix(t(Spectrum_df)), 
                              names = paste("YourFileDescription", 1:dim(Spectrum_df)[2]), 
                              groups = rep(factor("Factor"), dim(Spectrum_df)[2]), 
                              colors = rainbow(dim(Spectrum_df)[2]), 
                              sym = 1:dim(Spectrum_df)[2], 
                              alt.sym = letters[1:dim(Spectrum_df)[2]], 
                              unit = c("a.u.", "Domain"), 
                              desc = "Some signal. Describe it with 'desc'"){
  features <- c("freq", "data", "names", "groups", "colors", "sym", "alt.sym", "unit", "desc")
  Spectrum_chem <- vector("list", length(features))
  names(Spectrum_chem) <- features

  Spectrum_chem$freq <- freq
  Spectrum_chem$data <- data
  Spectrum_chem$names <- names
  Spectrum_chem$groups <- groups
  Spectrum_chem$colors <- colors
  Spectrum_chem$sym <- sym
  Spectrum_chem$alt.sym <- alt.sym
  Spectrum_chem$unit <- unit
  Spectrum_chem$desc <- desc

  # important step
  class(Spectrum_chem) <- "Spectra"

  # some warnings
  if (length(freq)!=dim(data)[2]) print("Dimension of data is NOT #samples X length of freq")

  if (length(names)>dim(data)[1]) print("Too many names")
  if (length(names)<dim(data)[1]) print("Too less names")

  if (length(groups)>dim(data)[1]) print("Too many groups")
  if (length(groups)<dim(data)[1]) print("Too less groups")

  if (length(colors)>dim(data)[1]) print("Too many colors")
  if (length(colors)<dim(data)[1]) print("Too less colors")

  if (is.matrix(data)==F) print("'data' is not a matrix or it's not numeric")

  return(Spectrum_chem)
}
Spectrum_chem <- dataframe2Spectra(Spectrum)
chkSpectra(Spectrum_chem)
```